# Why i cant see an image at my Tkinter Gui?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

****EDIT***
I just made my img and panel global , but i want them be in same line , how can i do that?

this is what is see now:
[image]

I am trying to display some image but something goes wrong and I can't see my image.
I understood that the problem is with other functions that I wrote (kmean), there I displayed a plot on my Tkinter. if I hide this function so the image works and display well

Cluster class:

```
 def kmean(self,df,top):
        result = KMeans(n_clusters=int(self.k), n_init=int(self.iterations)).fit(df)
        kmeans = result.predict(df)
        df['kMeans'] = kmeans
        figure = Figure(figsize=(5,5))
        plt=figure.add_subplot(111)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, top)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=600, pady=200)
        figure.suptitle('K-Means Clustering', fontsize=16)
        plt.set_xlabel('Social support', fontsize=16)
        plt.set_ylabel('Generosity', fontsize=16)
        plt.scatter(df['Generosity'], df['Social support'], c=result.labels_.astype(float))
        canvas.draw()
```

Gui class:
here I am trying to display image but its dosn`t works

```
         def cluster(self):
             cluster = Cluster(self.kNum,self.runs)
             cluster.kmean(self.dataFrame.df,top)
             cluster.countries(self.dataFrame.df)

             im=Image.open("name.png")
             img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
             panel = Label(top, image=img)
             panel.image = img
             panel.grid()
```

someone can explain to me what the problem please?

Comment: try  `global panel,img`  inside your cluster method

Comment: its looks that its works now , but there is a new issue ,  i just edited my post

Comment: what positioning system are you using,if it is `grid()` specify it to be in same row and diff column like `.grid(row=0,column=0)` and `.grid(row=0,column=1)`